# Set value of hidden input with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to set the value of the hidden field below using jQuery.

```
<input type="hidden" value="" name="testing" />
```

I'm using this code:

```
var test = $("input[name=testing]:hidden");
test.value = 'work!';
```

But its not working. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: For full clarity, jQuery returns a collection of DOM elements. test doesn't become the DOM element it becomes an array. To use plain ol' javascript a la .value, you can do test[0].value or loop over the collection if there is more than one.

Otherwise, test.val('work!') would work for you since it is a jQuery method rather than test.value which is a property of the DOM element object.

Answer (score 147):

You should use `val` instead of `value`.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('input[name="testing"]').val('Work!');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 37):

This worked for me:

```
$('input[name="sort_order"]').attr('value','XXX');
```

Answer (score 32):

```
$('input[name="testing"]').val(theValue);
```

Comment: strange, its supposed to do it

Comment: There isn't a problem because of "Type='hidden'" rather than "type='hidden'" is there? Not sure about mixed case attributes. Could be clutching at straws...

Comment: i think the problem here is the selector.. I think it should be `input[name="testing"` --> testing between quotes... Whenever setting some value doesn't work, try to get the element first.. If you don't get it, the problem isn't with .val(), but probably with the selector

Answer (score 10):

Suppose you have a hidden input with id XXX, if you want to assign a value to the following

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#XXX').val('any value');
    })
</script>
```

Comment: FYI, Code-only answers generally get flagged as low-quality and will usually be deleted.  Try posting some context / explanation with your answer if you'd like it to stick around and (possibly) get upvoted.

Comment: The selector you are using (`#XXX`) is for the `id` attribute. If you "named" an input XXX, the selector would be `input[name="XXX"]`.

Answer (score 8):

```
var test = $('input[name="testing"]:hidden');
test.val('work!');
```

Answer (score 5):

To make it with jquery, make this way:

```
var test = $("input[name=testing]:hidden");
test.val('work!');
```

Or

```
var test = $("input[name=testing]:hidden").val('work!');
```

See working in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sj6L9/).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set name , just giving an id is enough.

```
<input type="hidden" id="testId" />
```

and than with jquery you can use **'val()'** method like below:

```
 $('#testId').val("work");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set value to input hidden filed in this way also

```
 <input type="hidden" value="" name="testing" id-"testing" />
document.getElementById("testing").value = 'your value';
```

this is one of the method .