# JQuery - how to set value (but not display on page) for a html text field?

Tags: jquery, html

**Note:**
I have a situation where i can't set the value in **hidden input element**.

```
var size_val = $("#size_val").val();
var size_measure = $("#size_measure").val();
$("#size_val").val(size_val+' '+size_measure);
```

I want to set the value for the same textbox 'size_val' but don't want to show the new value on the page.

**Note:**
I know, i can set the value in **hidden field** but i've a situation where i **can't set** in hidden field.

Comment: but you are setting value using $("#size_val"), then definitely it will definitely set value $("#size_val"). where is your hidden field ?

Comment: @pedram I want to set the value for the same textbox 'size_val' but don't want to show the value in that textbox.

Comment: You want to chage the value of an `<input type="text">` but you don't want to show it?

Comment: @LutzHorn Yes bro.

Comment: An `input type="text"` has no hidden value. What do you have in mind?

Comment: @AvnishTiwary You can't change the value and display an other value. You can use data attribute example `data-value='your value'`.

Comment: @Alexis With the help of data-value, can i set the new value for the text field and also would the value not show in the textbox?

Comment: @Alexis - Now what you have noticed on below answer? Please check! Someone has copied my answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set value of hidden input with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802999/set-value-of-hidden-input-with-jquery)

Answer (score 4):

Well, that's because you are setting the value on the `#size_val` element.

You need to set the value on the hidden element you want, like this:

```
var size_val = $("#size_val").val();
var size_measure = $("#size_measure").val();
$("#id_of_hidden_element").val(size_val+' '+size_measure);
```

---

### UPDATE BASED ON OP EDIT

So, if I understand correctly what you need is not setting a **value on a hidden field** but to set a **hidden value on a field**.
We can do this with `attributes` on that field:

**Custom attribute:**

```
var size_val = $("#size_val").val();
var size_measure = $("#size_measure").val();
$("#size_val").attr("hiddenvalue",size_val+' '+size_measure);
```

To recover that value you can do this:

```
var hidden_value = $("#size_val").attr("hiddenvalue");
```

The html input would look like this:

```
<input type="text" value="showed value" hiddenvalue="hided value"/>
```

**Data attribute:**

```
var size_val = $("#size_val").val();
var size_measure = $("#size_measure").val();
$("#size_val").data("hiddenvalue",size_val+' '+size_measure);
```

The html input would look like this:

```
<input type="text" value="showed value" data-hiddenvalue="hided value"/>
```

To recover that value you can do this:

```
var hidden_value = $("#size_val").data("hiddenvalue");
```

Note that the "*hiddenvalue*" is just a name for the `attribute` we can use any other name.

Comment: I've edited the question. I don't want to set the value in hidden field.

Comment: Thx! I made an update that I think fullfill your needs

Comment: It worked for me. But one thing i'd like to ask that can i get the new value on server side by using name attribute.

Comment: Depends on server side language and control mangement in templates. For example in ASP.NET if you add the attribute runat="server" you can get on server side every attribute value but I don't think that this practices are common. There would be a few tricks that you can try but I think this is a topic for another question